# What's the best way of ensuring a Function argument is serializable?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, serializable

I'm writing a serializable class that takes several arguments, including a `Function`:

```
public class Cls implements Serializable {
    private final Collection<String> _coll;
    private final Function<String, ?> _func;

    public Cls(Collection<String> coll, Function<String, ?> func) {
        _coll = coll;
        _func = func;        
    }
}
```

`func` is stored in a member variable, and so needs to be serializable. Java lambdas [are serializable if the type they're being assigned to is serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda/22808112#22808112). What's the best way to ensure that the `Function` I get passed in my constructor is serializable, if it is created using a lambda?

1. Create a `SerializableFunction` type and use that:

   ```
   public interface SerializableFunction<F, R> implements Function<F, R>, Serializable {}
   ....
   public Cls(Collection<String> coll, SerializableFunction<String, ?> func) {...}
   ```

   Issues:

   - There's now a mismatch between the `coll` and `func` arguments, in that `func` is declared as serializable in the signature, but `coll` is not, but both are required to be serializable for it to work.
   - It doesn't allow other implementations of `Function` that are serializable.
2. Use a type parameter on the constructor:

   ```
   public <F extends Function<String, ?> & Serializable>
   Cls(Collection<String> coll, F func) {...}
   ```

   Issues:

   - More flexible than 1, but more confusing.
   - There's still a mismatch between the two arguments - the `func` argument is required to implement `Serializable` in the compile-time type heirarchy, but `coll` is just required to be serializable *somehow* (although this requirement can be cast away if required).

   **EDIT** This code doesn't actually compile when trying to call with a lambda or method reference.
3. Leave it up to the caller

   This requires the caller to know (from the javadocs, or trial-and-error) that the argument needs to be serializable, and cast as appropriate:

   ```
   Cls c = new Cls(strList, (Function<String, ?> & Serializable)s -> ...);
   ```

   or

   ```
   Cls c = new Cls(strList, (Function<String, ?> & Serializable)Foo::processStr);
   ```

   This is ugly IMO, and the initial naive implementation of using a lambda is *guaranteed* to break, rather than likely to work as with `coll` (as most collections are serializable somehow). This also pushes an *implementation* detail of the class onto the caller.

At the moment I'm leaning towards option 2, as the one that imposes the least burden on the caller, but I don't think there's an ideal solution here. Any other suggestions for how to do this properly?

**EDIT**: Perhaps some background is required. This is a class that runs inside [storm](http://storm.apache.org/), in a bolt, which is serialized to transfer to a remove cluster to execute. The function is performing an operation on the processed tuples when run on the cluster. So it is very much part of the class's purpose that it is serializable and that the function argument is serializable. If it is not, then the class is not usable at all.

Comment: Wouldn't the problem with option 2 exist just the same if there was no second parameter at all?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work if you receive a capturing lambda...

Comment: Ah yes, option 2 doesn't actually compile. I've removed it.

Comment: Why did you remove the second option? You only have to place the `public` modifier at the right location, i.e. *before* the declaration of the type argument. `public <F extends Function<String, ?> & Serializable> Cls(Collection<String> coll, F func) { …`

Comment: I get a compile error 'cannot infer type-variable F' when trying to pass a method reference

Comment: @thecoop: I guess, you are talking about the attempt to pass a lambda expression as it works with concrete types implementing both interfaces. So, if the compiler cannot infer the type argument for the lambda expression, you have to insert an explicit type cast (or provide type arguments). Then it’s not more concise than option 3 but it is still *enforcing* the constraint which is what your question is all about.

Comment: Java generics go just so far before becoming convoluted and ugly. If you want FP quality - expressed in code -, use a more functional JVM language like Scala. Though Scala has its own issues. Momentarily java generics + lambdas is reminiscent to C++ templates in the beginning: very nice, erratic, and to be used moderately. Overdone it will not develop productively with. I mean: **it will be fine not to specify the utmost.**

Comment: One of the primary reasons for using Java is type safety. Given that what you are doing throws type safety out of the window I think it should be seen as a hint that there is something fundamentally wrong with your design. Which is to say don't try and serialize functions, instead just serialize your data and use classes to store your functions.

Comment: @bhspencer added info as to why serialization is required

Comment: If I understand the use case you are using this to send code to a remote location and then perform remote code execution (something like 1990s agents). I would advocate for sending the class file to the remote machine and then using the class loader at run-time to load the class and execute and instance of it with the serialized data.

Comment: Serialization, unfortunately, throws all the rules out the window. It is a language feature that masqerades as a library feature. It is a dynamic typing feature that masquerades as a static typing feature. It violates all the rules of OO (objects are no longer exclusively created by constructors).  So, as much as folks like @bhspencer will want to wag their finger at you, once you're using serialization, you're already in a world of serious compromise, and you're left to choose the least bad of the alternatives in front of you.

Comment: @BrianGoetz in your opinion which is the least bad alternative for sending code to a server for remote execution?

Comment: @thecoop: you should understand that the Serialization process of lambda expressions [is not that simple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084460/2711488), it still depends on the class in which the lambda expression is defined. So the advantage of lambda expressions goes away when using Serialization. The most efficient way to transfer functions is to create an `enum` implementing the functional interface and having it’s constants implementing the desired behavior, then transfer these constants (that won’t transfer any data besides the `enum` class and constant name).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases the answer is: *don’t*.

You may notice that most classes of the JRE, even [`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject-java.lang.Object-) do not enforce `Serializable` in their signature. There are simply too many APIs not specifically to Serialization where the compile-time information about an object implementing `Serializable` gets lost and using them together with Serialization would require lots of type casting if the latter enforced their inputs to be `Serializable`.

Since one of your parameters is a `Collection`, you may get examples from that API:

[`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-):

> The returned list will be serializable if the specified list is serializable.

You will find more of these operations which care to retain the Serialization capability without retaining the `Serializable` compile-time type on the result.

This also applies to all non-`public` types, e.g. the results of `Collections.emptyList()`, `Arrays.asList(…)` and `Comparator.reverseOrder()`. They all are `Serializable` without declaring it.

---

Further, every class having more use cases than just getting serialized should refrain from enforcing to be always `Serializable`. That would hinder the uses where no Serialization is involved.

Regarding the `Collection` parameter, you may consider removing the serializable constraint at all. Normally, you protect your class against later-on changes to the collection you received. A simple solution is to copy the collection and when your doing it, you may use a type which supports Serialization.

Even if you want to avoid copying, the Serialization itself is a copying process per se, so you can simply create custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods storing the *contents* of the `Collection`, eliminating the need to have a `Serializable` collection.

---

To summarize it, usually the policy is that *if* the user of your class intends to serialize instances of it, it’s the responsibility of the user that all components put into it are themselves `Serializable`.

Comment: Added some more information as to why serialization is required