# Serializable Object.class

Tags: java, sonarqube, serializable, sonarlint

```
public class RegisterRequest implements Serializable {

    @NotNull(message = "Register may not be null")
    private Object register;

}
```

I got codeSmell from sonarLing `SonarLint: Make "data" transient or serializable.`

Because I have `Object.class` I can't add in this class `implements Serializable` also I can't `transient` because I need this object serialize.

How I can fix this codeSmeel by sonar lint?

Comment: My recommendation is to deactivate the rule. Trying to enforce serializable types at compile time via declarations contradicts common practice and will turn out to be impossible in a lot of scenarios. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31117279/2711488) and also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115005/whats-the-best-way-of-ensuring-a-function-argument-is-serializable/31117279#comment50251549_31115005)

Answer (score 0):

The thing with Object fields is, those do not implement the `Serializable` interface. SonarQube is saying that you're trying to serialize a field, in this case `Object register` which does not implement the interface. For your `register` field you should use a custom class which implements the `Serializable` interface.

Because of this SonarQube is telling you that you should either let `Object` implement the `Serializable` interface (which you can't) or mark it with `transient`.

Comment: If I use custom register field I will get same error in custom class also

Comment: So you made a class `Register` and implemented the `Serializable` interface in that class?

Comment: My register class also will have Object.class

Comment: @ValdyB with Object.class this won't work. You need to declare a class Register which holds your information. You can't use Object.class.

Comment: For my case I need only Object.class

Comment: @ValdyB What you could do would be create a class `CustomeObject` which extends the `Object` class and there implement the `Serializable` interface. Then you have the same behaviour as the `Object` class.