# Invalid lambda deserialization with Infinispan Cache and computeIfAbsent

Tags: wildfly, infinispan, jgroups

I’m toying with an **basic infinispan cluster** and I came across a puzzling error.

I’m basically implementing a shared map, holding just one Integer

Here is the code of my service

```java
package sandbox.infinispan.test.service;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.infinispan.Cache;

@Named("useThisOne")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CounterService implements ICounterService {

    private static final String KEY = "key";

    @Inject
    private Cache<String, Integer> cache;

    @Override
    public void inc(final int amount) {
        this.cache.put(KEY, Integer.valueOf(this.get() + amount));
    }

    @Override
    public int get() {
        return this.cache.computeIfAbsent(KEY, k -> Integer.valueOf(0)).intValue();
    }
}
```

**Cache** is produced with the following:

```java
package sandbox.infinispan.test.config;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.CacheMode;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalConfiguration;
import org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager;
import org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager;

@Dependent
class CacheProvider {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    private EmbeddedCacheManager defaultClusteredCacheManager() {
        final GlobalConfiguration g = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder() //
                .clusteredDefault() //
                .transport() //
                .nodeName(this.getNodeName()) //
                .clusterName("infinispanTestCluster") //
                .build();
        final Configuration cfg = new ConfigurationBuilder() //
                .clustering() //
                .cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC) ///
                .build();
        return new DefaultCacheManager(g, cfg);
    }
}
```

When there are at least two servers in the cluster, **computeIfAbsent** fails with

```
15:48:50,253 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (jgroups-7,myhostname-14393) ISPN000136: Error executing command ComputeIfAbsentCommand, writing keys [key]: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from otherhostname-44445, see cause for remote stack trace
```

which drills down to:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sandbox.infinispan.test.service.CounterService.$deserializeLambda$(java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
```

and finally to:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid lambda deserialization
        at sandbox.infinispan.test.service.CounterService.$deserializeLambda$(CounterService.java:10)
            ... 68 more
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
        in object of type java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda
```

If I rewrite my pretty nice fashionable code to the ugly following, it works.

```java
@Override
public int get() {
    Integer value = this.cache.get(KEY);
    if (value == null) {
        value = Integer.valueOf(0);
        this.cache.put(KEY, value);
    }
    return value.intValue();
}
```

How can I use the pretty **computeIfAbsent** way of doing things nowadays ?

---

Eclipse 2018-12, WildFly 14, java 10 on of the dev member of the cluster, CentOs 7, OpenJdk 10, WildFly 14 on the remote cluster member.

Thanks for your help

---

**Solved** (kinda)

Thanks to the help I received here, I transformed the lambda into an inner class :

```java
static class OhWell implements Serializable {

    static Integer zero(final String t) {
        return Integer.valueOf(0);
    }
}

@Override
public int get() {
    return this.cache.computeIfAbsent(KEY, OhWell::zero).intValue();
}
```

It works now, but it’s lots less nice than the neat lambda. So I’ll stick to the old-fashioned way – unless someone can think of a better way to do it.

---

**Further results:**

The following *static* inner class with a *static* method works

```java
static class StaticOhWell implements Serializable {

    static Integer apply(final String t) {
        return Integer.valueOf(0);
    }
}

@Override
public int get() {
    return this.cache.computeIfAbsent(KEY, StaticOhWell::apply).intValue();
}
```

The following *non static* inner class with a *non static* method fails :

```java
class NotStaticOhWell implements SerializableFunction<String, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer apply(final String t) {
            return Integer.valueOf(0);
    }
}

@Override
public int get() {
    return this.cache.computeIfAbsent(KEY, new NotStaticOhWell()::apply).intValue();
}
```

It fails with this error message **NotSerializableException: org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderCache**:

```
13:41:29,221 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (default task-1) ISPN000136: Error executing command ComputeIfAbsentCommand, writing keys [value]: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderCache
    Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field sandbox.infinispan.test.service.CounterService.cache
    in object sandbox.infinispan.test.service.CounterService@4612a6c3
    in field sandbox.infinispan.test.service.CounterService$NotStaticOhWell.this$0
    in object sandbox.infinispan.test.service.CounterService$NotStaticOhWell@4effd362
    in field java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.capturedArgs
    in object java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda@e62f08a
    in object sandbox.infinispan.test.service.CounterService$$Lambda$1195/1060417313@174a143b
```

---

**Final words (?)**

Using a “static lambda” (a *static* inner class implementing the **SerializableFunction** interface) worked too

```java
static class StaticSerializableFunction implements SerializableFunction<String, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer apply(final String t) {
        return Integer.valueOf(0);
    }
}

@Override
public int get() {
    return this.cache.computeIfAbsent(KEY, new StaticSerializableFunction()::apply).intValue();
}
```

---

**And the winner is…**

Making the class actually serializable by “*transienting*” the *Cache* allows to simply use a method of this class. No need to create an inner class!

```java
package sandbox.infinispan.test.service;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.infinispan.Cache;

@Named("useThisOne")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CounterService implements ICounterService, Serializable {

    private static final String KEY = "value";

    @SuppressWarnings("cdi-ambiguous-dependency")
    @Inject
    private transient Cache<String, Integer> cache;

    @Override
    public void inc(final int amount) {
        this.cache.put(KEY, Integer.valueOf(this.get() + amount));
    }

    @Override
    public int get() {
        return this.cache.computeIfAbsent(KEY, this::zero).intValue();
    }

    private Integer zero(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final String unused) {
        return Integer.valueOf(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        this.cache.clear();
    }
}
```

**Thanks all!**

Comment: Does the `CounterService` class exist on the remote node? Have you tried changing the lambda to an anonymous inner class?

Comment: @DanBerindei thanks, moving the lambda to an inner class (not anonymou though) did the trick.

Comment: I'm afraid you only moved the implementation to a nested class, `OhWell::zero` is still a lambda. But because it only references a static method in a nested class, it doesn't capture anything and it is definitely serializable.

Comment: Re-reading the description, I'm pretty sure now `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sandbox.infinispan.test.service.CounterService.$deserializeLambda$(java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)` means the `CounterService` class deployed on the remote node was compiled before you added the lambda, and your initial lambda would work if you deployed the same `CounterService` class on all the nodes.

Comment: @DanBerindei nope. I made very sure the exact same code was running in both wildfly(flies ?), and still Invalid lambda deserialization

Comment: A serializable inner class requires the enclosing class to be serializable, too.

Comment: Reading the docs of `Cache.computeIfAbsent()`, I understand that implementing a non-anonymous class implementing `SerializableFunction` is what the developers of Infinispan believe to be the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Unable to deserialize lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079307/unable-to-deserialize-lambda) the deserializer needs the actual code to be available. Are you sure that your application is already started on all other nodes in the cluster (the exact same version, including your lambda)?

The `computeIfAbsent()` sends the lambda directly to the data (and therefore handles the operation using one RPC, instead of first fetching the value and then writing it as the 'ugly code'). In WF, your application lives in a different classloader (module) than Infinispan and that might cause an issue.

Could you try to refactor your lambda into a class and see if you get similar problem? I am not that knowledgeable about WF, so there might be a mitigation for regular classes that is missing for lambdas.

Comment: Thanks. I refactored my lambda to using an inner class, implementing SerializableFunction<String, Integer>, and well, it worked !. Not sure how moving from a neat lambda to a bulky explicit inner class could make my code nicer… It does work, but I think I’ll stick to the obvious former way of doing things.

Comment: I don't say it's a better way (it's obviously less convenient) - just wanted to know if that works...

Comment: As you can see in my edited post, implementing SerializableFunction<String, Integer> did not actually work. I had to write a static method instead. Could you comment on that?

Comment: Implementing the Serializable interface is not enough to make the class actually serializable; if it's an inner class it hosts a reference to the outer class (CounterService) and that's not serializable because it has the non-serializable Cache field.

Comment: I don't think you need to use the `StaticOhWell` inner class; static method in CounterService should work as well. As you can see, that this leads to unrelated (and understandable) NotSerializableException. I don't fully understand the reasons for IllegalArgumentException, though.

Comment: I think even an non-static method in CounterService works too!