# How to compare functional interfaces / method references in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is it possible to do something like:

```
boolean isItMyMethod( Consumer<Object> aConsumer )
{
    return aConsumer.equals( this::myMethod );
}
```

This does not compile. It does if I assign this::myMethod to an intermediary variable, but then the result is always false.

Comment: what is the type of myMethod?

Comment: What is the use case ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? BTW directly passing method reference won't work because target type of lambdas and method references should be a Functional Interface, and `Object` is not that.

Comment: You can't rely on `.equals` on lambdas or method references to return consistent results, anyway.

Comment: Or, in other words, with the current implementation, you can say `Consumer<Object> c1=this::myMethod, c2=this::myMethod;` and both, `c1==c2` or `c1.equals(c2)`, will evaluate to `false`. So you can fix your code to `aConsumer.equals((Consumer<Object>) this::myMethod )` but it will always yield `false` (with the current JRE implementation). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28190304/2711488

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target type for a method reference, or a lambda, should be a functional interface. Since `equals()` method takes an `Object`, which is not a functional interface, it fails to compile. Now you would say, why? Well, a lambda expression or a method reference is at runtime implemented as an instance of a class implementing that functional interface. A FI contains just a single abstract method, thus for a lambda `x -> Sysout(x)`, the left part becomes the parameter of that method, and right part becomes body.

Now there can be many functional interface, providing such method signature. That means same lambda expression can be compiled to implementation of different FIs. Now when you pass a lambda to an `Object` reference like this:

```
Object ob = x -> Sysout(x);
```

which FI do you expect JVM to instantiate? This results in certain ambiguity, and hence is not allowed. But by pre-assigning a lambda to a FI reference:

```
Consumer<Object> consumer = x -> Sysout(x);
```

you've assigned a concrete meaning to the lambda, which then later on can be assigned to any of its super type reference.

```
Object ob = consumer;
```

Now as for why `equals()` method returns `false`, you can guess it. Since lambda is an instance of a class constructed at runtime, which would provide implementation of the abstract method in FI, on what basis would you want two `Consumer` references to compare? Since there is no `equals()` method overridden, it will invoke the implementation in `Object` class, which just compares the reference. Implementation looks like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    return this == ob;
}
```

Certainly `aConsumer == bConsumer` will return `false`, if both are referring to 2 different lambdas / method references.

Comment: `aConsumer == bConsumer` may return `false`, even if both are referring to the same lambda expression / method reference…

Comment: Why `equals()` is not overridden?