# How do I remove lambda expressions/method handles that are used as listeners?

Tags: java, lambda, listener, methodhandle

Java 8 has introduced [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), which is a great thing. But now consider rewriting this code:

```
class B implements PropertyChangeListener {
    void listenToA(A a) {
        a.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }

    void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        switch(evt.getPropertyName()) {
            case "Property1":
                doSomething();
                break;
            case "Property2":
                doSomethingElse();                case "Property1":
                doSomething;
                break;

                break;
    }

    void doSomething() { }
    void doSomethingElse() { }
}

class A {
    final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

With lambda expressions and method references, it is no more necessary to have `B` implement `PropertyChangeListner` as we can write

```
class B {
    void listenToA(A a) {
        // using method reference
        a.addPropertyChangeListener("Property1", this::doSomething);
        // using lambda expression
        a.addPropertyChangeListener("Property2", e -> doSomethingElse());
    }

    void doSomething(PropertyChangeEvent evt) { }
    void doSomethingElse() { }
}

class A {
    final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    void addPropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    void removePropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }
}
```

I think the new code is not only shorter but also cleaner and easier to understand. But after reading the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190304/two-exact-method-references-are-not-equal) (duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095875/is-there-a-way-to-compare-lambdas) one, but I think question and answer are more crisp), I can see no way to implement a method called `stopListening()` which would remove the listeners again.

I am sure that I am not the first one to stumble on this. So has anyone found a nice solution on how to use method handles as shown in this example and still being able to remove the listeners again later?

**UPDATE**

That was fast. Building on the answers by Mike Naklis and Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I ended up with this:

```
class B {
    void listenToA(A a) {
        a.addPropertyChangeListener("Property1", doSomething);
        a.addPropertyChangeListener("Property2", doSomethingElse);
    }

    final PropertyChangeListener doSomething = evt -> {};
    final PropertyChangeListener doSomethingElse = evt -> {};
}
```

Comment: exactly. instead of declaring a method, declare a functional object (with lambda expression). this is a useful strategy in several use cases.

Comment: However, think about whether the function (i.e. the functional object) can be static (in this case, yes). If every object has its own instance of the function, it may be a waste of memory.

Comment: @ZhongYu Thank you. But since the listeners have to do something with the `B` instance they belong to, I cannot make them static in my program.

Comment: what about `evt.source`?

Comment: That would be `A`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can declare your listeners as follows:

```
private final PropertyChangeListener myProperty1Listener = this::doSomething;
private final PropertyChangeListener myProperty2Listener = e -> doSomethingElse());
```

then, you can add your listeners:

```
// using method reference
a.addPropertyChangeListener( "Property1", myProperty1Listener );
// using lambda expression
a.addPropertyChangeListener( "Property2", myProperty2Listener );
```

and you can remove them:

```
a.removePropertyChangeListener( "Property1", myProperty1Listener );
a.removePropertyChangeListener( "Property2", myProperty2Listener );
```

Comment: You beat me to it as I was typing (1+)

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambdas and still use variables. For example, if you had:

```
class B {
    private PropertyChangeListener listener1 = this::doSomething;
    private PropertyChangeListener listener2 = e -> doSomethingElse(); 

    void listenToA(A a) {
        // using method reference
        a.addPropertyChangeListener("Property1", listener1);
        // using lambda expression
        a.addPropertyChangeListener("Property2", listener2);
    }
```

Then it would be easy to remove listener1 or listener2 when and where needed.

Also there are other ways, since the PropertyChangeSupport object has a `getPropertyChangeListeners()` that would allow removal of all listeners in a for loop if need be.

```
class A {
    final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    void addPropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    void removePropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    public void removeAllListeners() {
        for (PropertyChangeListener l : pcs.getPropertyChangeListeners()) {
            pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
        }
    }
}
```