# On Java lambda equality and/or instantiation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Why does the snippet below print true on second pass through? Should it not be a new instance?

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Supplier<Long> old = () -> System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            /* false true true
            Supplier<Long> foo = System::nanoTime;*/

            Supplier<Long> foo = () -> System.nanoTime();

            /* false false false
            Supplier<Long> foo = new Supplier<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long get() {
                    return System.nanoTime();
                }
            };
            //*/

            System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n", foo == old, foo, old);

            old = foo;
        }
    }
}
```

```
false Foo$$Lambda$2/122883338@1ddc4ec2 Foo$$Lambda$1/1534030866@133314b
true Foo$$Lambda$2/122883338@1ddc4ec2 Foo$$Lambda$2/122883338@1ddc4ec2
true Foo$$Lambda$2/122883338@1ddc4ec2 Foo$$Lambda$2/122883338@1ddc4ec2
```

Comment: I imagine it's a compiler optimisation.  There's no need for a new instance for each iteration of the loop, so the compiler doesn't bother.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095875/is-there-a-way-to-compare-lambdas

Comment: Why have you edited to re-add unrelevant comments ? (Just wondering, maybe they are relevant)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I think they add some context, `::` behaves like `()->`, but not like `new`

Comment: Talk is cheap, the code stands for itself. The comments provide no additional value IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out this [article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood) about how lambdas are implemented.

Essentially the compiler turned your two `System.nanoTime()` into the following static methods on your class:

```
static Long lambda$1() {
    return System.nanoTime();
}

static Long lambda$2() {
    return System.nanoTime();
}
```

And then created a constant reference to each target-typed to `Supplier<Long>` using the [`LambdaMetaFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html). Frankly, I'm disappointed that the Java compiler didn't realize that the lambda body was identical and only create one instance. If the Java compiler were sufficiently smart, every line should have printed `true`!

Comment: Even if the compiler was smart enough to fold `lambda$1()` and `lambda$2()` into one method, different lambda creation sites referring to that method still would cause creation of different object instances (and even different classes). This can easily be proven by using a method reference like `System::nanoTime` multiple times as these *do* point to the same target method as no synthetic method is generated. Still, they yield to different objects *given Oracle’s current implementation*.

Comment: Note that the observed behaviour is NOT MANDATED! The compiler or runtime MIGHT only allocate a single object and reuse it for both the lambda expressions. Such an optimisation might be added without notice in a future Java version, or might kick in during application runtime when the code is JIT optimised. See [Holger's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/452775).