# Mocking java8 stream.map

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, java-8, mockito

I am using mockito how can I mock stream.map() call.

I tried something like this which return null.

```
@Mock Stream<String> stringStream;
@Mock Stream<String> upperCaseStream;

when(stringStream.map(String::toUpperCase)).thenReturn(upperCaseStream);
syso(stringStream.map(String::toUpperCase));
```

This prints null.

I am looking for a correct way of mocking that would return 'upperCaseStream' in output.

Comment: Have you actually initialized `upperCaseStream`?

Comment: I have initialized the mocks that's not the problem. Without initialization stringStream.map(String::toUpperCase) would throw NPE.

Comment: These are simple, heavily-tested library functions. Why are you trying to mock them?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? This sounds like a [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Don't.  Just don't mock these things.  They aren't meant to be mocked.  Use real values, if small toy ones.  But this is the kind of thing you shouldn't be mocking in the first place.

Comment: I understand that using test data is the right way to go, but wanted to know if mocking was the only option what effort would it take.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the identity of method references or lambdas is not guaranteed to be the same even if the calls look identical. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095875/is-there-a-way-to-compare-lambdas)

I don't know much about Mockito, but I believe it checks if there exists a value that a `when` registered, this might invlove a call to equals somewhere which is not guranteed to work here. For example:

```
Function<String, String> fn1 = String::toUpperCase;
Function<String, String> fn2 = String::toUpperCase;
System.out.println(fn1.equals(fn2)); // false on my machine
```

You can simply store the reference in a variable and use it later on

```
Function<String, String> toUpperCase = String::toUpperCase;
when(stringStream.map(toUpperCase)).thenReturn(upperCaseStream);

System.out.println(stringStream.map(toUpperCase));
```

Btw, I really don't understand why would ever need to mock `Stream<String>` where you can simply do `Stream.of("foo","bar")`

Comment: "Identity of method references or lambdas is not guaranteed to be the same even if the calls look identical". This explains why my approach is failing. Thanks.