# Java 8 lambda and alpha equivalence

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, lambda-calculus

I am wondering, is any nice way (if it is possible at all) to implement an [alpha-equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence) comparison in Java-8?

Obviously these two lambda-s are alpha-equivalent. Let us suppose that for some circumstances we want to detect this fact. How it can be achieved?

```
Predicate<Integer> l1 = x -> x == 1;
Predicate<Integer> l2 = y -> y == 1;
```

Comment: You would need to find a way to obtain a canonical representation of your `Predicate` or to test them over their whole domain, and I don't see any practical way to do either

Comment: This may be of some help, but I'm not sure how much - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095875/is-there-a-way-to-compare-lambdas

Comment: well you could Serialize the lambda expression and compare the bytes, I have not tried this though

Comment: @holi-java that's not what the OP wants...

Comment: @Eugene first of all your idea about some byte code comparison is really interesting and it is exactly what I have been thinking about. Secondly, my goal here is slightly more theoretical, because it is really difficult to describe my practical idea here in brief.

Comment: If the case is as simple as in the given example, a comparison of JVM instructions would solve the problem, because you can ignore the variable name and even the generic type, and only compare the list of instructions. A framework like [ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-bytecode-asm) could help interpreting and comparing bytecode instructions, but that's probably alot of work.

Comment: @Eugene hi, what about the OP meaning ? could you show me a formular ?

Comment: @SME_Dev I am sure that any workable solution given as an answer will be much appreciated not only by my self :) Your idea could work

Comment: @holi-java please, consider learning lambda-calculus theory, this will reveal you the idea of my question

Comment: @Andremoniy that is hard for me. my english is so bad, sir.

Comment: @holi-java in this case I have no idea how to help you understand my question :-)

Comment: hi, someone has already point it out. compare the instructions. so the question is how java implements the equivalent  lambdas. Am I right, sir?

Comment: I'd like to know what are your thought. +1

Comment: @Andremoniy serializeable could be an option, but Im thinking about the order or instructions in a bigger lambda expression, they could be equivalent, but in *different* order... Ill have to try that

Comment: You can use instrumentation to read the lambda class, then use something like the asm library to work out if they are equivalent, which will likely be enough for a trivial example like you provided, but it wont work for more complicated cases.

Comment: @Andremoniy I'm surprised that you accepted the answer. Maybe people are still experimenting for a solution based on serialization, bytecode reading or similar approaches ...?

Comment: @Marco13 Perhaps :) As soon as somebody provides such kind of answer, I will consider to change my decision.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sub>I'm going out on a limb with this answer, but it may be worth mentioning this:</sub>

There is no way to do this. As Brian Goetz pointed out in an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098805/3182664), there are no specified, reliable ways of obtaining the "contents" of a lambda, in that sense.

But (and now comes the vague, handwaving part) :

There is no way to do this **yet**.

It might be possible to do this in the future. Maybe not with Java 9, but later. The [Project Panama](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/panama/) has ambituous goals, among them, giving the developer a deeper access to lambdas, aiding in further (runtime) optimizations, translations and processing.

And recently, [Radosław Smogura posted in the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/panama-dev/2017-June/000612.html) :

> I try to capture lambda expression to get them as expression tree during runtime. I’m able to do it for simple lambdas like (o) -> (var == var) && ((varX == varX) && (someField + 1 == 1)), so later user can use (missing) API to examine tree.
>
> Right now tree can be accessed with code like this:
>
> ```
> Method m = BasicMatadataTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("lambda$meta0");
> Expression e = (Expression) m.invoke(null);
> BinaryExpression top = (BinaryExpression) e;
> BinaryExpression vars = (BinaryExpression) top.getLefthandExpression(); // represents (var == var)
> (VariableExpression) vars.getLefthandExpression() // represents first var, and it’s reference equal to vars.getRighthandExpression() as it’s same variable
> ```
>
> ...

The key point here may be the comment:

> represents first var, and it’s **reference equal** to vars.getRighthandExpression() as it’s same variable

<sup>(e.b.m)</sup>

So if I understood your question and this mailing list post correctly, then it might be possible to determine the equivalence between such expressions: Comparing the tree structure would be fairly trivial (given the functionality sketched above). And then it might boil down to treating two `VariableExpression` as being "equal", regardless of the actual variable *name*.

The mailing list message points to the repositories:

> - https://bitbucket.org/radoslaw_smogura/java-lambda-metaexpression-jdk9-langtools/branch/metaexpr
> - https://bitbucket.org/radoslaw_smogura/java-lambda-metaexpresions-jdk/commits/branch/metaexpr

(Disclaimer: I have not tested this, and don't know how to get this running (or whether it works at all) - but to my understanding, it is at least *very* close to what the question was actually about).

Comment: basically the short version would be - no way; *might happen*, but not sooner then jdk-10. *Might* being the keyword.

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks! +1 But will still wait for some time if somebody finds any result with serialization

Comment: @Andremoniy Sure, this answer is not profound enough to be *acceptable*. There might be options with serialization or ASM or other bytecode magic, and I'd also be curious to see them (even if - and this is likely - they would be somehow implementation dependent or relied on other unspecified details). But I think that eventually, the path sketched in the mailing list (@Eugene ;-)) **might** be one that leads towards a real, proper API for achieving the goal.

Comment: I finally understand what the OP want to do. plus one. he want to compare the lambda body's logic are equivalent . Am I right, sir?  but there are many  combinations for the same logic.

Comment: @holi-java Yes. The *formal* definition of the equivalence is explained on [Wikipedia: Lambda Calculus Alpha Equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence). To my understanding, one core aspect of the question was whether there is a way to programmatically obtain the "contents" of a lambda (so that one could implement the logic that is described on the Wikipedia site). (I think that the serialization approach would only work for *very* limited cases, if at all, but that's another issue).