# Mock method invocation with Method Reference as Param

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, method-reference

Is there any way to mock something like this:

```
when(mock.methodCall(Class::gettter)).willReturn(...)
when(mock.methodCall(Class::gettter2)).willReturn(...)
```

Header for methodCall

```
methodCall(Function<Class, String> function)
```

When I use `ArgumentMatchers.eq(...)` mock does not return value from `willReturn`

Comment: A method reference `Class::gettter` may return every time a new `Function<Class, String>`.   Only ["two lambdas that are reference-equal (==) are going to compute the same function"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098805/2838289).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mock the wrong thing. You're starting to create a complex mocking logic. A better question would be - why can't the mock use the `Function` passed into it?

Look at how you can `doAnswer`, where your mocking code makes use of the inputs to the mock object to calculate a fake answer, rather than just use a list of pre-ordained answers.

To advise you more, why don't you post more of the code you're trying to test and the test scenario you're trying to achieve.