# Verify BiConsumer as method reference in Unit Test

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, powermock, method-reference

I have some logic quite similar to this, where i have unit and different fields that can be updated during request.

```
public class Unit {
    int x;
    int y;

    public void updateX(int x) {
        this.x += x;
    }

    public void updateY(int y) {
        this.y += y;
    }
}

public class UpdateUnitService{
    public Unit update(int delta, BiConsumer<Unit, Integer> updater){
        Unit unit = getUnit(); //method that can`t be mocked
        updater.accept(unit, delta);
        // some save logic

        return unit;
    }
}

public class ActionHandler{
    private UpdateUnitService service;

    public Unit update(Request request){
        if (request.someFlag()){
            return service.update(request.data, Unit::updateX);
        }else {
            return service.update(request.data, Unit::updateY);
        }
    }
}
```

And I need write some test for checking what function was called. Something like this.

```
verify(service).update(10, Unit::updateX);
verify(service).update(10, Unit::updateY);
```

How to write test like this using ArgumentCaptor or something else?

Comment: You should test whether the operation does the right thing, which is whether the `Unit` contains the right values afterwards. How it does it, e.g. by calling a particular method via method reference, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way (in current implementation of Java) to compare two lambdas and/or method references. For more details read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098805/10584605).

What you could do (in case `getUnit()` is unmockable) is to check whether the two method references do the same thing when invoked. But you can't verify any unknown side effects.

```
public void verifyUpdateTheSameField(Integer value, BiConsumer<Unit, Integer> updater1, BiConsumer<Unit, Integer> updater2) {
    Unit unit1 = // initialize a unit
    Unit unit2 = // initialize to be equal to unit1

    actual.accept(unit1, value);
    expected.accept(unit2, value);

    assertThat(unit1).isEqualTo(unit2);
}
```

And then:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Integer> valueCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
ArgumentCaptor<BiConsumer<Unit, Integer>> updaterCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(BiConsumer.class);

verify(handler.service, times(1)).update(valueCaptor.capture(), updaterCaptor.capture());

verifyUpdateTheSameFields(valueCaptor.getValue(), updaterCaptor.getValue(), Unit::updateX);
```

*Note: This approach will work only if `Unit` overrides `equals`.*