# Is there a type that would hold all possible setter references of java class regardless of the type being set?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Let's assume we have a very simple class:

```
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I'm doing a simple binder class to populate a user and would like to signal the required properties.

```
UserBinder binder = new UserBinder(user)
    .requires(User::setId)
    .requires(User::setName);
```

The above would signal that both properties are required. Of course I could pass the values `"id"` and `"name"` instead of the method references. But it seems that passing the setter is very appropriate since that setter needs to be called inside the binder.

The following works great:

```
public void requires(BiConsumer<User, Long> r) // for User::setId;
public void requires(BiConsumer<User, String> r) // for User::setName;
```

But the following fails:

```
public void requires(BiConsumer<User, ?> r)
```

Is there a type that would hold all possible setter references of java class regardless of the type being set?

Comment: Bluntly: this is probably impossible.  You _cannot_ assume one `BiConsumer` is ever equal to another, even if both are entirely equivalent.  You can't put them in a set, you can't `==` on them, you can't introspect them to see what method they represent.  It's a nice idea, but you almost certainly won't be able to make it work -- and, even worse, it might _look like_ it works but not actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a generic parameter to the `requires` method:

```
public <T> void requires(BiConsumer<User, T> consumer)
```

Now this:

```
new UserBinder(new User())
    .requires(User::setName);
```

compiles fine.

---

*You told that you need to store received consumers in some collection and check if the collection already contains some `consumer`*

Unfortunately you can't do it easily (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095875/is-there-a-way-to-compare-lambdas?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

As a workaround you can create a `@FunctionalInterface` extending `Serializable` with the same method signature as in the `BiConsumer` and compare serialized bytes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794336/6486622). But remember that you *can't rely on this behavior*

Comment: Got that far. But what if I want to keep track of the consumers storing in a set? The set would have to a signature of  `Set<BiConsumer<User, ?>>` but then checking `set.contains(User::setId)` does not compile.

Comment: @RicardoMarimon you can use signature `Set<BiConsumer<User, Object>>`, but seems it won't help in your case because comparing lambdas is not so easy (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095875/is-there-a-way-to-compare-lambdas)). Recently I was thinking about the same design but unfortunately seems it is not so easy to implement. Maybe you can consider using [hibernate validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) in conjunction with your binder? Or maybe you can elaborate more about your requirements on `Binder` so I could suggest something else?

Comment: thanks for the reference to the question. I was under the impression that you could compare lambdas and from what I have read, there are no guarantees. Maybe in the case of methods references that I'm using. I'm going to explore further since I got it to work with `public <T> boolean isRequired(BiConsumer<User, T> consumer) { return requires.contains(consumer); }` with a `Set<Object>`.

Comment: @RicardoMarimon `set.contains(User::setId)` does not compile but `set.contains((BiConsumer<User, Long>) User::setId)` compiles fine

Answer (score 4):

You could bind type possibly using :

```
<T> void requires(BiConsumer<User, T> r) {
}
```

Also, if you were to mandate just these parameters you could have created the custom constructor for the required fields as :

```
public User(Long id, String name)
```

to ensure the instantiation of the object must have these attributes.