# Must implement default interface method?

Tags: java, java-8, default-method

Here is a simplified example showing my problem:

```java
import java.util.List;

public interface SingleTask extends List<Runnable>, Runnable {
    default Runnable get(final int x) {
        if (x != 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return this;
    }

    default int size() {
        return 1;
    }
}

import java.util.AbstractList;

public class MyTask extends AbstractList<Runnable> implements SingleTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

In `SingleTask` I provide implementations for the methods `get` and `size`, which are the only abstract methods from `AbstractList`. However, when I compile `MyTask`, I still get errors like:

> The type MyTask must implement the inherited abstract method
>   AbstractCollection.size()

or

> MyTask.java:3: error: MyTask is not abstract and does not override abstract method get(int) in AbstractList

(depending on the compiler). I am, of course, using java 8.

So I have two questions:

1. Why am I getting these errors? I was expecting it to recognize the default implementations.
2. If it's not supposed to work like that, then what's the simplest way to use those two methods in `MyTask` without copying the whole code?

Comment: Don't make your tasks extend `List<Runnable>` (what does that mean semantically anyway?), instead create an interface `Task` with a `public List<Runnable> getRunnables();` method. Failing that, simply make `SingleTask` an abstract class instead of an interface.

Comment: Worth noting that Eclipse is choking on the `size()` not implemented: this is probably an Eclipse bug. `javac` 1.8.0_51 is choking on `get(int)` not being implemented and it's right: it is not implemented.

Comment: @biziclop it's supposed to be a list of tasks; SingleTask is a singleton implementation

Comment: @Tunaki both `size` and `get` are equally implemented/not implemented

Comment: @aditsu `SingleTask is a singleton implementation` There, you've just said it. If it's an implementation, it should be a class, not an interface. What you're trying to use default methods here for looks a bit like traits, which they aren't designed for.

Comment: @biziclop it implements the singleton "feature" (or trait, I guess?), not the actual task; anyway, regardless if this is how *you think* I should be doing this, the question is about why it's not working this way.

Comment: If that worked, you got a `List` implementation where even crucial methods like `equals` or `hashCode` are broken as they might end up with a `StackOverflowError`. What’s the point of this recursive data structure?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24016962/2711488

Answer (score 6):

Forcing `SingleTask` implementors to also implement all the methods of `List` isn't very elegant, and default methods aren't meant to be used to define trait-like entities, which your `SingleTask` interface looks like.

There are several reasons why default methods-as-traits is a bad idea, the most obvious one being that any implementor can simply override your default method, ruining your trait.

And this is exactly what is happening here: since `AbstractList` explicitly declares `get()` and `size()` as `abstract`, it means `SingleTask` will inherit them, rather than the default implementations you may have had in a superinterface.

[JLS 8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8):

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass and direct
>   superinterfaces all abstract and default (§9.4) methods m for which
>   all of the following are true:
>
> ...
>
> - No concrete method inherited by C from its direct superclass has a signature that is a subsignature of the signature of m.

Bearing all that in mind the simplest solution is probably this:

```
public abstract class SingleTask extends AbstractList<Runnable> implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public final Runnable get(final int x) {
        if (x != 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public final int size() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Its drawback is that your tasks must extend `SingleTask` and thus can't extend anything else, on the plus side though they don't need to deal with the task also being a `List`, they only need to implement `run()`.

In the long run though, I would prefer composition over inheritance, and tasks simply returning a list of runnables rather than themselves being one.

Comment: I wasn't forcing SingleTask implementors to also extend AbstractList, but it looks like you are. Also, you made SingleTask a class, which means I can't extend a different class if I want to use this. And you didn't even attempt to answer my first question.

Comment: @aditsu `I wasn't forcing SingleTask implementors to also extend AbstractList` Yes, you do, and that's what is causing the problems. I'll edit my answer to cover that too.

Comment: Wrong, with my code, SingleTask implementors only need to implement List's methods. There's nothing in SingleTask about AbstractList!

Comment: @aditsu You're right, they can also implement all the `List` methods by hand. (On the plus side, at least their code would compile then.)

Comment: I think you have a good point about composition vs inheritance, I guess you would use that for implementing traits?

Comment: @aditsu Yes, if you want pluggable behaviour, composition is your best bet in Java. I find it personally quite annoying as I really like traits and like you, I thought default methods could do the job. But it turned out quite quickly that it isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why am I getting these errors? I was expecting it to recognize the default implementations.

I think @biziclop correctly covered that in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35770359/1876620). In short, as `AbstractList` declares `get(int)` and `size()` methods as abstract, these take precedence over your default implementations in `SingleTask`.

> 2. If it's not supposed to work like that, then what's the simplest way to use those two methods in `MyTask` without copying the whole code?

The easiest would be to override `get(int)` and `size()` methods in `MyTask`, so that they delegate to your default methods in `SingleTask` interface:

```
public class MyTask extends AbstractList<Runnable> implements SingleTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    @Override
    public Runnable get(int index) {
        return SingleTask.super.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return SingleTask.super.size();
    }
}
```

With this approach, you would be kind of *delegating* to your default methods in `SingleTask`. I don't think this is a bad thing (at least, you don't need to use an attribute). Besides, it makes sense to write these methods, so that you can choose what interface provides the default implementations.