# why Java 8 interface static methods cannot override Object class methods

Tags: java, java-8

Reading article about java 8 `static` and `default` interface methods, and i found

> Java interface static method is visible to interface methods only,

so my guess is that static interface methods will not inherited by the concrete classes

at the same articel

> We can’t define interface static method for Object class methods, we
>   will get compiler error as “This static method cannot hide the
>   instance method from Object”. This is because it’s not allowed in
>   java, since Object is the base class for all the classes and we can’t
>   have one class level static method and another instance method with
>   same signature.

if interfaces are not inherited from `Object` class and `static interface methods` will not be inherited by the concrete class, Why we can’t define interface static method for Object class methods

EDIT

why we can't add `public static int hashCode(){//SOME_CODE;}` into interface?

Comment: Then you wouldn't ever be able to inhert from said `interface`. What would such a `interface` be for?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, your comment is not clear, can you add more explanation please. Thanx

Comment: @MeladEzzat What exactly is the question/problem you have? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Progman, why we can't add public static int hashCode(){} into interface

Comment: We can't do `public static int hashCode() {...}` in a regular class either.

Comment: @Radiodef, I know and i understand why we cannot do it in regular classes. the point is why we cannot do it in interfaces.

Comment: What would be the point of `hashCode` being `static` (even in interface)? Anyway related post: [Java8: Why is it forbidden to define a default method for a method from java.lang.Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24016962)

Comment: "Java interface static method is visible to interface methods only," is not true. There are many static or default methods which are available outside of interface like in case of `interface Comparator` we can use `reverseOrder()` which is static method available to "outside world" or `thenComparing(Function)` which is default method.

Comment: @Pshemo, by 'visible' it means visible like any regular inherited method, not through the interface name.

Comment: Visibility describes *scope* from which we can use member of type, not *how* we are accessing it.

Comment: @Pshemo, the bottom line is 'interface static methods are not inherited by the implementing classes'.

Comment: @MeladEzzat I don't know why this question is marked as duplicate. I too am confused after reading your question and would like to know a better reason.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal, I don't know why  Progman and GhostCat marked the question as duplicate. it is completely different question

Comment: @Progman it is not the same question

Comment: @GhostCat, it is not the same question

Comment: All interfaces are always subtypes of class java.lang.Object, so trying to declare a method with signature int hashCode() would be trying to override Object's int hashCode(), but overriding is impossible for a static method. The reasons are not different for a class or for an interface.

Comment: @Progman This is not a duplicate. You should reopen this question or comment a better answer here