# How to make default `clone()` in an interface?

Tags: java, cloneable

The following code compiles w/o errors:

```
public interface ICloneable {

    default ICloneable clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var object = new ICloneable() {

        };


        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

But at runtime it says:

```
ICloneable.java:9: error: clone() in Object cannot implement clone() in ICloneable
        var object = new ICloneable() {
                                      ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

Is it possible to overcome?

Comment: you need to Override the clone method on the new ICloneable() {};  call

Comment: The idea of `default` is not to override :)

Comment: if you want to use the default then create a class that implements that interface then instaciate that class other then that you need to Override the method

Comment: Possibly related: [Java8: Why is it forbidden to define a default method for a method from java.lang.Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24016962)

Answer (score 5):

> The following code compiles w/o errors

No it doesn't.

That error you see is in fact a compile error.

### Why you get that error

I'm not sure if you understand that `clone()` is, itself, a method that `java.lang.Object` already has: [javadoc of Object.clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()).

A `default` implementation in an interface **never** overrides any implementation found anywhere in a class's actual class hierarchy. Meaning, your `clone()` default impl in your `IClonable` interface is *never* used - as all classes have `Object` in their hierarchy and its `clone()` takes precedence.

However, `IClonable` must have a `public` `clone()` method - but the `clone()` you get 'for free' from `j.l.Object` is `protected`, hence your code does not compile here.

> Is it possible to overcome?

Sure. Various options exist.

#### The best: Don't call it `clone()`

Given that `clone()` is already taken by j.l.Object, find another word. Unless, of course, your *intent* was to use an interface to force both a default impl *and* force it public, in which case...

#### Use abstract classes instead

If `ICloneable` was an abstract class, you wouldn't get this error.

#### ... otherwise

No, this cannot be fixed. There is no way to tell `javac` to take the default impl of an interface even though an impl exists in the class hierarchy.

NB: Using `IClonable` style naming is discouraged. Using the `clone()` functionality sort of half baked into java (and Object's own `clone()` is part of this functionality) is strongly discouraged. Make immutable types where possible. If not possible, think through what cloning might mean and just make a method for it. The general principle of 'you can clone me' is broken as a concept. For example, cloning an immutable is pointless, yet, having the `clone()` method of an immutable type be written as `public Object clone() { return this; }` is misleading. As a concept, it's not salvagable. There's a reason e.g. arraylist has `new ArrayList<T>(otherArraylist)` as suggested way to clone one, *not* `List<T> clone = otherArrayList.clone();`.

Comment: Then, can I clone with some othe class, like I can fix flaws of `Object`-s `toString` with `Objects`'? For example, it could exist `Objects#clone` method?

Comment: "Just clone this" as a concept is broken as I explained. In java, it's not even clear what 'please clone this arbitrary object' even means!

Comment: To deal with "broken concepts" a polymorphism was invented: authors of some library are able to coin their own specific concept, valid within their library

Comment: Sure. But you need to define what 'clone' means, your objects cannot contain arbitrary objects (only objects of types within your own little space that has very well defined cloning behaviour), and thus `Objects.clone` should not exist (it should perhaps be called `Shapes.clone` if you wrote a shapes library, etc.