# Does interface in java extends object class internally?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

As you can see the below code where we can override equals method from an object class:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface abc
{
    void meth1();
    default void meth2(){
    };
    boolean equals(Object obj);
}
```

So according to the above code does interface in Java extends object class internally?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't, am `interface` isn't a class. Of course you can declare an `equals` method in it - but it's pretty much a no op, since every class implementing the interface will have that method anyway.

Comment: "As you can see the below code where we can *override* equals method from an object class." that is now what is happening here. You are *re-declaring* that method, not *overriding* it. You are not providing code/body of that method which would *override* (replace) previous code/body from java.lang.Object#equals method. To provide body for method in interface such method must be marked as `default` (or static) but that is not allowed for this case as explained in [Java8: Why is it forbidden to define a default method for a method from java.lang.Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24016962)

Answer (score 2):

> So accroding to the above code does interface in java extends object class internally?

No. interfaces cannot extend classes at all, and `java.lang.Object` is a class, not an interface.

> As you can see the below code where we can override equals method from an object class.

The Java Language Specification explicitly calls out that any interface is considered a functional interface if you follow this list of steps:

- **remove** any signatures in it, defaulted or not, that match precisely anything defined in `java.lang.Object`.
- **remove** anything that has a `default` implementation.
- Disregard inner types and fields.

Are you left with **precisely** one method definition?

Then it is a functional interface. `@FunctionalInterface` isn't required; that is merely compiler-checkable documentation, which causes the compiler to error out if the interface does not fit the above requirements. (It's a: Do nothing if all is well, fail to compile otherwise).

The fact that you disregard all methods that j.l.Object already defines is **part of the JLS** - it isn't some internal 'oh it extends object'. No, the code in `javac` explicitly checks.

Answer (score -1):

> *"... So according to the above code does interface in Java extends object class internally?"*

Contrary to everyone's responses, I believe I *did* read this somewhere.
Although, this doesn't mean they are wrong—it depends on what you mean by *"internally"*.

Here is the *Java Language Specification* entry.

*[Java Language Specification – 4.3.1. Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)*.

> *"An object is a class instance or an array. ...*
>
> *... A class instance is explicitly created by a class instance creation expression (§15.9)."*

So, in terms of a *"class instance creation expression"*, from *15.9*,

> *"ClassInstanceCreationExpression:*
>   *UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression*
>   *ExpressionName . UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression*
>   *Primary . UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression*
>
> *UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression:*
>   *new [TypeArguments] ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate ( [ArgumentList] ) [ClassBody]*
>
> *ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate:*
>   *{Annotation} Identifier {. {Annotation} Identifier} [TypeArgumentsOrDiamond]"*

As *ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate* defines it, the compiler will interpret the *interface* as an object.
Or, maybe a better way to say it is, the *interpreter* is going to schedule the interface as an object.

Essentially, this is referring to the *anonymous inner-class*.

```java
abc abc = new abc() {
    @Override
    public void meth1() {

    }
};
```